# Unable to Configure Network on Homeserver Behind "Fritz Box" Home Router

Tags: networking, dhcp, netplan, router, ipv4

**Description:**

I've encountered a puzzling network issue with my homeserver setup and I'm seeking guidance to resolve it.

**Problem:**

My homeserver, behind a "Fritz Box" home router, experiences connectivity hiccups. While IPv4 pinging between my laptop and the homeserver works flawlessly, pinging the home router (192.168.8.1) fails with IPv4 (IPv6 works). However, intriguingly, pinging the router succeeds when obtaining the IP via DHCP from the router.

**Network Details:**

Home Router Information:
Address: 192.168.8.1
Subnet Mask: 255.255.248.0
DHCP Range: 192.168.9.1 to 192.168.15.254
Local DNS Server: 192.168.8.1 (same as the home router)

**Configuration Attempts:**

DHCP Setup on Homeserver:

```
System Information:
------------------

Ubuntu Version:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy


Netplan Configuration:
----------------------
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp6s0:
      dhcp4: true


Network Information:
-------------------
IP Address info for enp6s0:
2: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:89:a5:64:90:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.9.23/21 metric 100 brd 192.168.15.255 scope global dynamic enp6s0
       valid_lft 863949sec preferred_lft 863949sec
    inet6 fe80::8e89:a5ff:fe64:9091/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Route info for enp6s0:
default via 192.168.8.1 proto dhcp src 192.168.9.23 metric 100
192.168.8.0/21 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.9.23 metric 100
192.168.8.1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.9.23 metric 100

Resolv.conf:
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search fritz.box

Link info for enp6s0:
2: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:89:a5:64:90:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Ping info for 192.168.8.1:
PING 192.168.8.1 (192.168.8.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.8.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.645 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.8.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.448 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.8.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.456 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.8.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.431 ms

--- 192.168.8.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3055ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.431/0.495/0.645/0.087 ms

Ping info for 8.8.8.8:
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=14.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=119 time=13.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=119 time=13.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=119 time=12.9 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.941/13.489/14.074/0.411 ms

NSLookup info for fritz.box:
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   fritz.box
Address: 192.168.8.1
Name:   fritz.box
Address: fd00::52e6:36ff:fe75:f8a0


NSLookup info for google.com:
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.250.185.110
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4001:827::200e
```

Static Setup on Homeserver:

```
System Information:
------------------

Ubuntu Version:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy


Netplan Configuration:
----------------------
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp6s0:
      addresses:
      - "192.168.8.2/21"
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.8.1
        search:
        - fritz.box
      routes:
      - scope: "link"
        from: "192.168.8.2/21"
        to: "default"
        via: "192.168.8.1/21"


Network Information:
-------------------
IP Address info for enp6s0:
2: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:89:a5:64:90:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.8.2/21 brd 192.168.15.255 scope global enp6s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8e89:a5ff:fe64:9091/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Route info for enp6s0:
192.168.8.0/21 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.8.2

Resolv.conf:
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search fritz.box

Link info for enp6s0:
2: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:89:a5:64:90:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Ping info for 192.168.8.1:
PING 192.168.8.1 (192.168.8.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.8.2 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.8.2 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.8.2 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.8.2 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 192.168.8.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3059ms
pipe 4

Ping info for 8.8.8.8:
ping: connect: Network is unreachable

NSLookup info for fritz.box:
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find fritz.box: SERVFAIL


NSLookup info for google.com:
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find google.com: SERVFAIL
```

**Troubleshooting Steps Taken:**

I've extensively logged configurations and attempted various troubleshooting steps without success.

Interestingly, the DHCP setup appears to produce more routes compared to the static setup.

**Request for Assistance:**

Would appreciate any insights or suggestions to resolve this connectivity issue between my homeserver and home router using a static configuration.

Thank you for your time and assistance!